# How to permanently disable the num lock key in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, numlock

This key is close to others on my keyboard which contributes to some accidental key presses.  I would like this key to be a no-op.  I am mainly interested in a solution that works when I log in via Unity desktop.  Gnome-terminal is a critical app where this causes me problems.  I don't log into TTY very often, so I don't think I need a solution that works in that domain if it is different from the Unity desktop.

Comment: A no-op where? In the UI, Terminal, TTY? Everywhere??? (The solution depends on this)

Comment: I updated the question to rule out TTY if that complicates things. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use multiple keyboard lay-outs? (and no: everywhere is easier then "somewhere")  ;-)

Comment: All of my keyboards are US QWERTY.  However, there are different keyboards I use to interact with this machine.  One is a Goldtouch keyboard that is directly plugged in.  Another is a attached to my mac laptop that I use in the context of remote desktop.  The Mac keyboard gives me no problems.  I also have a Goldtouch keyboard at home (similar to my office one) that I use when plugging the Macbook into my home KVM switch.

Comment: Oh, it's a Mac...  Sorry, I won't be able to help you then...  I know nothing about Mac keyboards.

Comment: But the macbook keyboard is not a problem.  In fact, in cursory inspection I don't even see a num lock button on that keyboard.  It's the goldtouch keyboards that give me this difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

To add context to SetJmp's answer in case you don't want to read through UbuntuForums:

1. Run `xev` in a terminal
2. Press the key that you want to disable (in this case, num lock).  Note the keycode (in my case, 77)
3. Run `xmodmap -e 'keycode number = NoSymbol'`.  In my case, this was `xmodmap -e 'keycode 77 = NoSymbol'`

I haven't tested if the keycode is standard across computers or if additional steps are needed to make it persist across reboots.

Comment: 77 on my dell laptop too. According to that linked forum discussion "To make it permanent, put this command in the System, Preferences, Sessions, Startup Programs folder, Add."

Comment: To start "Startup Applications Preferences", press ALT + F2 and run `gnome-session-properties`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach helpful:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=842970